# Installing the localized version of firebaseui in a react project

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I have build the FirebaseUI as described [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web#developer-setup).

I can see the local version in the dist folder, however, I'm unsure how to include it in my react project.

The docs state:

```
import firebaseui from './npm__{LANGUAGE_CODE}';
```

I feel I'm missing a step in between.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web/blob/master/README.md#option-2-npm-module

You should be ok with

```
import * as firebaseui from 'firebaseui'
```

Comment: so I then just add the localized css and js into the firebaseui folder?

Comment: Into your application index is ok, import the css you need